Reduced form of Bhargava cubes
Let $A \in \mathbb{Z}^{2} \otimes \mathbb{Z}^{2} \otimes \mathbb{Z}^{2}$ be a Bhargava cube. We have a natural action of $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})^{3}$ on the space of Bhargava cubes, and I wonder if we have a reduction theory of cubes analogous to the theory of binary quadratic forms.
For binary quadratic forms, let's assume $D = b^2 - 4ac<0$. Then $f(x, y) = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ is reduced if $|b|\le a\le c$ and if $b \ge 0$ whenever $a = |b|$ or $a = c$. Reducing procedure (finding a reduced form $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$-equivalent to a given form) is essentially the same as finding a representative of a $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$-orbit of $z \in \mathcal{H}$ (complex upper half plane) in the famous fundamental domain.
For Bhargava cube, we can always find a normal form of a given cube which has $1$ and $0$'s for all three adjoint vertices:

but the normal form is not unique in general. Especially, it is not clear what is the most "reduced normal" form, maybe in terms of the sizes of $d, f, g, h$. Maybe the best choice of a reduce form is not a normal form, but a cube corresponds to a representative of a $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})^{3}$-orbit of some element of some space, in a "nicely described" fundamental domain. Maybe one can even hope the three associated quadratic forms $Q_1^A,Q_2^A,Q_3^A$ of $A$ are all reduced, but it is not clear for me if this is always possible. (More precisely, for a given cube $A$ and corresponding three quadratic forms $Q_1^A, Q_2^A, Q_3^A$ whose Gauss composition is zero, we can ask an existence of a cube $A_0$ where $Q_i^{A_0} = \text{reducedform}(Q_i^{A})$.) It is very likely that this is already mentioned in some other Bhargava's papers, but I couldn't find it.

There are now many books and survey articles that discuss the cubes. I imagine some give the sort of detail you want. Let me look for those... https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/fbouyer/gauss_composition.pdf    ;;;;;; https://math.colorado.edu/~kstange/papers/notes-on-Bhargava.pdf

@WillJagy I checked the papers you mentioned before and couldn't find, but maybe I missed. Let me know if you found one.

I doubt a satisfying answer can be given. The only "nice" theory of reduced forms is in the case of positive definite forms, as you described in your post. Even for indefinite forms there is no "canonical" reduced form; in general, the number distinct reduced forms per class corresponds to the size of the regulator, or the length of the period of the continued fraction of the square-root of the discriminant. One can certainly define a notion of "reduced" as in the case of indefinite forms, but it likely will not be canonical.

@StanleyYaoXiao That makes sense. Is there any possibility to have a nice theory for certain class of cubes, e.g. all three quadratic forms associated to a cube are positive definite?

The answer to your question of whether all three quadratic forms can be simultaneously reduced is "yes".  The reason is just that the map $A \mapsto (Q_1^A, Q_2^A, Q_3^A)$ from cubes to triples of binary quadratic forms is equivariant for the action of $\mathrm{SL}_2^3$.

Thanks, I didn't know that, and I also found why I didn't aware of it. The original Bhargava's paper (Higher composition law I) uses the convention $Q_i(x, y) = -\det(xM_i - yN_i)$, while more recent articles uses $Q_i(x, y) = -\det(xM_i + yN_i)$ (which is not a big problem, since they are related as inverse of Bhargava cubes). I was using the first convention, but we need to use the second convention for the equivariance. (Continues...)

(...Continues) Otherwise, we need a twist: the action of $(\gamma_1, \gamma_2, \gamma_3)$ on $A$ corresponds to the action of $(i(\gamma_1), i(\gamma_2), i(\gamma_3))$ on associated quadratic forms, where $i: (\begin{smallmatrix} r & s \ t & u \end{smallmatrix}) \mapsto (\begin{smallmatrix} r & -s \ -t & u \end{smallmatrix})$. Anyway, I guess the current best choice is to define reduced cube as being all the associated forms reduced (at least for the negative discriminant cases).
